# Trigger modal card from menu item not top-level menu - HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding and hope someone can help be understand where I am going wrong.  I am having a problem with getting a modal card popup to trigger from a navbar-item.  Everything that I have tried so far triggers the modal at the top menu item.  Each of the navbar-items on the drop down will have a link to a modal card.
Thank you in advance for your help!!

```js
const item = document.querySelector(".navbar-item");
const modalBg = document.querySelector('.modal-background');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

item.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.classList.add('is-active');
});

modalBg.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal.classList.remove('is-active');
});
```

```html
<section>
  <nav class="navbar has-shadow" role="navigation" aria-label="dropdown navigation" id="navbar_link_modal">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-burger" id="burger">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-menu" id="nav-links">
      <div class="navbar-start">
        <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
          <a class="navbar-link" data-target="#modal">Ford</a>
          <div class="navbar-dropdown">
            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Explorer
                            </a>
            <a class="navbar-item" href="#framingLumber">
                                Focus
                            </a>
            <a class="navbar-item">
                                Flex
                            </a>
            <a class="navbar-item">
                                F-150
                            </a>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>

<div class="modal is-active" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-card" id="framingLumber">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p class="modal-card-title">Modal title</p>
      <button class="delete" aria-label="close"></button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-card-body">
      <!-- Content ... -->
    </section>
    <footer class="modal-card-foot">
      <button class="button is-success">Save changes</button>
      <button class="button">Cancel</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the item you want div or a? The same class was used for both div and a. I think it means a, but to do that, you have to use querySelecotrAll.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting your modal at your top-level menu as `data-target="#modal"` which is wrong because there is no element with id 'modal'.
You need to do this at your menu item as `data-target="#framingLumber"` where`framingLumber` is id of your modal and `href` is not needed.
So your code that would look like this:

```
<div class="navbar-menu" id="nav-links">
    <div class="navbar-start">
        <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
            <a class="navbar-link">Ford</a>
                <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                    <a class="navbar-item">Explorer</a>
                    <a class="navbar-item" data-target="#framingLumber">Focus</a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">Flex</a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">F-150</a>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point.  It should be <a> since there are several items items on the drop down.

Comment: I moved the data-target to the .navbar-item but all of the cards for that div show whenever any item, including the top-level item.  The cards are stacked on top of each other.  I would like to be able to click each item on the drop down and have only that card popup.